# Liquibase Not Updating Spring Boot Web Application

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I recently deployed a spring boot 1.4.0 web application and I noticed that liquibase did not perform an update. I have no problem with my spring boot 1.3.2 web application.

Was something introduced to Spring Boot 1.4.0 that would cause liquibase to not execute?

Comment: This is sounds like a bug. I would try to enable full logging and see what happens. Also, probably, you should create issue for that.

Comment: You wouldn't happened to know the package the liquibase integration is under?

Comment: They're here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase

Comment: Run app with `--debug` and see whether this autoconfiguration was activated or not.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I'm creating a war file for deployment, but I don't believe the extraction of the war is executing liquibase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked down the issue to liquibase-core package was not included in order to the Spring Boot autoconfigurations to execute.

It's not entirely clear why the liquibase-gradle-plugin did not include the required package.